# unknow namespace in Crystal Reports in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, crystal-reports, namespaces

I create Crystal report in C# winform. but in report.cs, get error from namespace:

```
****using CrystalDecisions.Shared;**
    **using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;**
    **using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;****


    public class rptReport : **ReportClass** {

        public rptReport() {
        }
```

I added emergency dll for this namespace, but it get error.

Comment: for example:the namespace "Engin" doesn't exit!

Comment: here you need to check dll in bin folder,dll version,dll reference in web.config,also which namespace it shows missing ?

Comment: in toolbax, i haven't crystal report viewer!!!! why?? instead of , i have report viewer! it's equivalent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the Crystal runtimes installed or haven't added the references to your project.